# create a list of data with value from multiple one to many relationsship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I have the table structure with the list of the id's selected from the drop down.
Lets say in the following format:

`id,teacher_id,batch_id,course_id,program_id,depart_id`

this fields get saved to database through ajax call. Now i wanted to get the name associated with this `id's`

I have a function Like this:

```
public function store(StoreEmployeesRequest $request)
{
   $teacherCourse = TeacherCourse::create($request->all());
}
```

Here, after the `TeacherCourse` has been created, i wanted to get all the value associated with `$teacherCourse->teacher_id` from table `TeacherCourse` 
and merge the value and create the array in the following format:

```
{
    "id":8,
    "program":"Master of Computer", //with program_id from program table
    "course":"software engineering" //with course_id from course table
},
{
    "id":7,
    "program":"Bachelor of Pharmacy", //with program_id from program table
    "course":"Structure Programing" //with course_id from course table
}
```

Relationship in `TeacherCourse`

```
public function course()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(Course::class,'course_id');
}

public function program()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(Program::class,'program_id');
}
```

I was trying to get the value using this operation but failed. How can i create a single array by getting the value from multiple table?

```
$teacherCourse = $teachercourse->program->map(function ($program) 
{
    return $program->name;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$teacherCourse = $teachercourse->map(function ($teacherCourse) 
{
    return [ 
             'id' => $teacherCourse->id,
             'program' => $teacherCourse->program()->pluck('name'),
             'course' => $teacherCourse->course()->pluck('name');
           ];
})->toArray();
```

I hope help you

Comment: let me try the solution and get back to you!

Comment: i am getting a nested array, i just want a string name and course to be bind on 'program` and `course`

Comment: edit code to program()->first()->name or program->name
@AkshayKriti

Comment: i think `lists` should be changed to `pluck`

Comment: @AkshayKriti if you want select a column only yes you should use pluck,